# Calculate coefficients of permutations

Tags: matrix, summation, permutation, coefficients

Let's say

$a=(12345)+(41235)-(51234)-(54123)$ 
$b=(12345)+(21345)-(31245)-(32145)$

And i need to calculate coefficients of $\sum_{\pi\in S_5}\lambda_{\pi}*\pi$ multiplied by a*b (from the left).

Other words if $a*b*\sum_{\pi\in S_5}\lambda_{\pi}*\pi=\sum_{\pi\in S_5}\mu_{\pi}*\pi$, then

i want to get transition matrix from $\lambda_\pi$ to $\mu_\pi$.

i ve tried this

```
v[a_,b_,c_,d_,e_] :=f[a,b,c,d,e]+f[b,a,c,d,e]-f[c,a,b,d,e]-f[c,b,a,d,e]
w[a_,b_,c_,d_,e_] :=v[a,b,c,d,e]+v[d,a,b,c,e]-v[e,a,b,c,d]-v[e,d,a,b,c]

Sum[a[i]*Permute[w[a, b, c, d, e], i],
  {i, GroupElements[PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}], Cycles[{{1, 2}}]}]]}
 ]
```

Comment: And you want to do this with the computing software *Mathematica*? How are you representing your permutations? Please include some of the code that you have tried so that we don't have to completely reproduce what you've done.

Comment: yes, i want to compute it on mathematica, and i am beginner at mathematica, i am reading tutorials and didn't success in coding.

Comment: Please edit your post with the code (don't include it in a comment).

Comment: I need some clarification. Let's assume we're going to work with matrix representations of these permutations. (1) When you are adding or subtracting the permutations above, does that correspond to adding or subtracting the matrices? Or does `+` correspond to composition of permutations and `-` to composition with the inverse of the following permutation? (2) What are $\lambda_{\pi}$ and $\mu_{\pi}$? (3) Is `*` composition of permutations? Or is this the permutation `pi` acting on a vector `lambda`? etc. Please provide more details!

Comment: * means composition of permutations

Comment: For example a*(1,3,2)+b*(1,2,3)-c*(1,3,2)=(a-c)*(1,3,2)+b*(1,2,3), where a,b,c are scalars, $\lambda_\pi$ and $\mu_\pi$ are scalars too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity, let's take as a representative element from the group algebra,

```
v = Cycles[{{1, 2, 3, 4}}] - Cycles[{{1, 2, 4, 3}}] - Cycles[{{1, 3, 2, 4}}] + Cycles[{{1, 3, 4, 2}}];
```

and consider the group

```
grp = GroupElements[PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{1, 2, 3, 4}}], Cycles[{{1, 2}}]}]];
```

Since this group is of size 24, the matrix that we construct had better be a 24-by-24 matrix. What we need to do:

- Multiply every element in `grp` by `v` to find the list of group algebra elements resulting from the composition of `v` with the group element.
- Extract from each of these the coefficients of the group elements.

The second bullet point is easily accomplished using `CoefficientArrays`. To accomplish the first bullet point, we have to define the addition operations for the group algebra by modifying `PermutationProduct`. We will do this using replacement rules.

Define

```
distributePermutations[expr_] := expr //. {
  PermutationProduct[x_Plus, b_] :> (PermutationProduct[#, b] & /@ x),
  PermutationProduct[n_ x_Cycles /; FreeQ[n, Cycles], b_] :> n PermutationProduct[x, b]
 }
```

This encodes the linearity of addition and scalar multiplication in the ring (for the first element anyway, which is all we'll neeed here; it is easy to extend this to the second element by adding two new rules). For instance,

```
elem = PermutationProduct[v[1, 2, 3, 4], Cycles[{{1, 3}}]]
(* (Cycles[{{1, 2, 3, 4}}] - Cycles[{{1, 2, 4, 3}}] - Cycles[{{1, 3, 2, 4}}] + Cycles[{{1, 3, 4, 2}}]) \[PermutationProduct] Cycles[{{1, 3}}] *)
```

Notice that `PermutationProduct` does not distribute. So we apply our function:

```
elem // distributePermutations
(* -Cycles[{{1, 2, 4}}] + Cycles[{{2, 3, 4}}] - Cycles[{{2, 4, 3}}] + Cycles[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}] *)
```

So now, we map the permutation product over the list of group elements:

```
lst = distributePermutations@PermutationProduct[v, #] & /@ grp
(* { {Cycles[{{1, 2, 3, 4}}] - Cycles[{{1, 2, 4, 3}}] - Cycles[{{1, 3, 2, 4}}] + Cycles[{{1, 3, 4, 2}}],
      -Cycles[{{1, 2, 3}}] + Cycles[{{1, 2, 4}}] + Cycles[{{1, 4, 2}}] - Cycles[{{1, 4}, {2, 3}}],
      ... } *)
```

and finally, extract the coefficients of the group elements as a `SparseArray`:

```
mat = CoefficientArrays[lst, grp][[2]];
Dimensions@mat
(* {24, 24} *)
mat // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: That is exactly i needed, thanks a lot!